# Indexed access vs variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

At various places, an element from array is being used at index. Instinct says replace it with a variable pointing to that element and use it. But is there any other difference than for better readability/management?

Example 1:

```
if (cols[i]["Type"] === 4) {
    this.someFunc(cols[i]["Name"], cols[i]["Value"].VarA, cols[i]["Value"].VarB);
}
```

Example 2:

```
var col = cols[i];
if (col["Type"] === 4) {
    this.someFunc(col["Name"], col["Value"].VarA, col["Value"].VarB);
}
```

Comment: Example 2 will be slight faster, using cached version.

Comment: You can write `col.Value.VarA`. You win 3 caracters

Comment: if you want to improve readability use dot notation

Comment: @Tushar For that kind of optimization, the compiler will likely take care of it anyway.  There's probably 0 runtime difference.

Comment: @JosephMarikle other than the first pass, trivial in this case but worth noting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to me that referencing the value directly via variable is faster than referencing the value via array element:

https://jsfiddle.net/cLf7k35n/

```
var test = 4;
var myArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

console.time("array_reference");
if (myArray[4] === 4) {
  console.log(myArray[4]);
}
console.timeEnd("array_reference");

console.time("variable_reference");
if (test === 4) {
    console.log(test);
}
console.timeEnd("variable_reference");
```

Check the console for the timers. In the specific, non-complex example I made, the array reference seemed to be at least 1.2 milliseconds slower.

Comment: Forked your fiddle to include variable assignment and ran the tests. On average, it was 3 times faster on average to do via variable. https://jsfiddle.net/p0cj3tzg/

Answer (score 1):

Example 2 will not need to do multiple array lookups so will be slightly faster.
That being said, the JIT will most likely hoist that out for you.

In my opinion Example 2 is more readable and thus easier to maintain, so I would go with that.

Also as [R3tep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3083093/r3tep) has stated, you can use `col.Type` and `col.Value.VarA` to improve readability further.

Comment: Your answer is relevant too, but the other answer provided an example to test. Thanks for your answer.